# How would I append multiple items to the list without predefining the number of values that can be entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add items to a list using pythons tkinter as gui. The user can choose the number of values they would like to enter and the program should save those items separately into the same list. Currently The program only appends the last value entered by the user into the list. For example currently if the user chooses to enter 2 values only the second valueis being added to the list. I've posted my exact code below. I'd appreciate if somebody points me in the right direction.

```
def multiple_chords_num():
    global num_chords_screen
    num_chords_screen = tk.Toplevel(root)
    num_chords_screen.grab_set()

    # geometry
    center_screen(300, 250, num_chords_screen)

    # other screen settings
    num_chords_screen.title('Transposition Tool')
    num_chords_screen.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    tk.Label(num_chords_screen,text = '\n\nHow Many Chords Would you like to Transpose?\n').pack()

    num=tk.Entry(num_chords_screen)
    num.pack()#pevents from object returning 'None'

    tk.Label(num_chords_screen,text = '').pack()
    ttk.Button(num_chords_screen, text = 'OK', command = lambda: multiple_chords(num)).pack(ipadx = 10, ipady = 1)

def multiple_chords(num):

    global multiple_chords_screen
    multiple_chords_screen = tk.Toplevel(root)
    multiple_chords_screen.grab_set()

    # geometry
    center_screen(300, 250, multiple_chords_screen)

    # other screen settings
    multiple_chords_screen.title('Transposition Tool')
    multiple_chords_screen.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    num=int(num.get())#obtains num value and turns it into integer
    for i in range(0,num):
        tk.Label(multiple_chords_screen,text = 'Enter Chord:').pack()
        chord=tk.Entry(multiple_chords_screen)
        chord.pack()#Prevents 'chord' from returning None


    ttk.Button(multiple_chords_screen, text = 'OK', command =lambda : a(chord.get(),num)).pack(ipadx = 10, ipady = 1)


def a(chord):
    u_list.append(chord)
    print(u_list)
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner as you can see in the multiple_chords function I have a for loop that generates the number of values that can be entered basis previous user input. just outside that loop I have placed a button that should append the user values to a list but it only appends the last value entered by the user -- that is the problem

Comment: `chord` can keep only one element and it keeps only last `Entry` - you have to keep all `Entry` on list  - and send this list to function `a`. Function `a` need `for` loop to get values from every `Entry` and append to `u_list`

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python collect input  in list", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chord` can keep only one element. In every loop you assing new `Entry` to this variable so finally it keeps only last `Entry`.

You have to keep all `Entry` on list and send this list to function `a`.

Function `a` needs to use `for` loop to get values from every `Entry` and append to `u_list`

More or less:

```
    # list for all entry    
    all_entry = []

    for i in range(0,num):
        tk.Label(multiple_chords_screen,text = 'Enter Chord:').pack()
        chord=tk.Entry(multiple_chords_screen)
        chord.pack()#Prevents 'chord' from returning None
        # keep entry on list
        all_entry.appen(chord)

    # send all_entry to `a`
    ttk.Button(multiple_chords_screen, text='OK', command=lambda : a(all_entry, num)).pack(ipadx = 10, ipady = 1)


def a(all_entry):
    # get all values
    for entry in all_entry:
        u_list.append(entry.get())
    print(u_list)
```